# how to pick an element from an array containing different data types, using offset and ordinal in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Based on this page [accessing array elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing-array-elements), I created an array called `some_numbers` with two datatypes(string and int). Here is the query to pick an element from the array but it is not working.

```
WITH sequences AS
  (SELECT array<struct<subject as string, marks as int64>>[("mat",87),("phy",45),("che",45),("zoo",78),("eng",87)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT array<struct<subject as string, marks as int64>>[("mat",87),("phy",45),("che",45),("zoo",78),("eng",87)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT array<struct<subject as string, marks as int64>>[("mat",87),("phy",45),("che",45),("zoo",78),("eng",87)] AS some_numbers)
SELECT some_numbers,
       some_numbers[OFFSET(1)] AS offset_1,
       some_numbers[ORDINAL(1)] AS ordinal_1
FROM sequences;
```

I have the following error:

> Error: Syntax error: Expected "," or ">" but got keyword AS at [3:32]
>   –

Comment: "but it is not working" -> what's the error you get?

Comment: Error: Syntax error: Expected "," or ">" but got keyword AS at [3:32]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost identical query, but working:

```
WITH sequences AS (
   SELECT           [STRUCT("mat" AS subject,87 AS marks),("phy",45),("che",45),("zoo",78),("eng",87)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT [STRUCT("mat" AS subject,87 AS marks),("phy",45),("che",45),("zoo",78),("eng",87)] AS some_numbers
   UNION ALL SELECT [STRUCT("mat" AS subject,87 AS marks),("phy",45),("che",45),("zoo",78),("eng",87)] AS some_numbers
)
SELECT some_numbers,
       some_numbers[OFFSET(1)] AS offset_1,
       some_numbers[ORDINAL(1)] AS ordinal_1
FROM sequences;
```

(for future questions, please include errors obtained and desired outcomes)

Comment: ya it is working and also, I don't know how to arrange the array in descending order.

Comment: please start a new question, stating your goal, what you tried, how it failed, and the desired results